# Browser Feature Detection with NGINX

Tags: http, nginx

Does anyone know of a plugin for NGINX that allows for the server to provide a specific file based on the features of the browser? For example:

```
if(Browser.Features.CSS3) {
  url.rewrite .../super_combined_css.css
}
else {
  url.rewrite .../basic_combined_css.css
}
```

I'm assuming it would just have a predefined list of browsers that exists that fall into certain categories (say CSS3 support, CSS animations, SVG support, etc...). Once a request comes in then it just analyzes the user-agent string to figure out what category the browser falls into.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such thing as a feature detection plugin or third party yet. You can however detect modern or ancient browsers using this module:

http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpBrowserModule

**UPDATE**

Find the new docs [here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_browser_module.html)!